# Fauna query language relations

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs, faunadb

I wanna write my graphql backend side with using FQL but I can't handle create and connect to FQL

My backend NodeJS code:

```
  async createNew(data) {
    const query = q.Create(
      q.Collection('comments'),
      { data }
    )

    const result: values.Document<Comment> = await this.client.query(query);
    result.data._id = result.ref.id;

    return result.data;
  }
```

And I run this code in my GraphQL playground

```
  createComment(data: {
    user: {
      create: {
        username: "1"
        password: "1"
        email: "1"
        gender: MALE
        birthday: "2021-01-01"
        country: "1"
      }
    }
    creationDate: "2021-05-04T17:07:00Z"
    content: "hello"
    likes: 1
    ballot: {
      connect: 296290209590411781
    }
  }) {
    user {
      username
    }
    ballot {
      title
    }
  }
```

I expect this code will create a new user and connect a ballot with this comment but I get this sad result in FaunaDB comments collection:

[FaunaDB results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfNST.png)

I wrote next code that does it for me but I'm convinced that this is an anti-pattern described [here](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/tutorials/basics/#lambdas)

```
  async createNew(data) {
    if(data.user) {
      let id;
      if(data.user.create) {
        const user = await this.userService.createNew(data.user.create);
        id = user._id;
      }
      data.user = q.Ref(
        q.Collection('users'), id ?? data.user.connect
      );
    }

    const query = q.Create(
      q.Collection('comments'),
      { data }
    )

    const result: values.Document<Comment> = await this.client.query(query);
    result.data._id = result.ref.id;

    return result.data;
  }
```

The code above demonstrate create and connect for users, and I guess this code will be quite exhaustive for each relation. I wanna write all FQL in one query but I really have no idea how to implement it

I have added schemas only with Comment - User relation, Ballot has a similar logic. My schema in a nutshell: Users has Ballots, Ballots has Comments, Comments has parent Ballot & User

My fauna schema:

```
type User @collection(name: "users") {
  username: String!
  email: String!
  password: String!
  birthday: Date!
  gender: Gender!
  country: String!
  createdBallots: [Ballot!]! @relation
}

enum Gender {
  MALE
  FEMALE
  OTHER
}

type Comment @collection(name: "comments") {
  user: User!
  creationDate: Time!
  content: String!
  likes: Int!
  ballot: Ballot!
}
```

I'm trying to use generated GraphQL Schema:

```
scalar Date
scalar Time
scalar Long

type Comment {
  _id: ID!
  likes: Int!
  content: String!
  creationDate: Time!
  user: User!
  ballot: Ballot!
  _ts: Long!
}

type User {
  birthday: Date!
  email: String!
  username: String!
  _id: ID!
  country: String!
  createdBallots(
    _size: Int
    _cursor: String
  ): BallotPage!
  gender: Gender!
  password: String!
  _ts: Long!
}

enum Gender {
  MALE
  FEMALE
  OTHER
}

type Mutation {
  createComment(data: CommentInput!): Comment!
  createUser(data: UserInput!): User!
}

input CommentInput {
  user: CommentUserRelation
  creationDate: Time!
  content: String!
  likes: Int!
  ballot: CommentBallotRelation
}

input CommentUserRelation {
  create: UserInput
  connect: ID
}

input UserInput {
  username: String!
  email: String!
  password: String!
  birthday: Date!
  gender: Gender!
  country: String!
  createdBallots: UserCreatedBallotsRelation
}
```

Comment: What's your schema?

Comment: Update with schema

Comment: Is the schema you shared what you uploaded or the generated schema after you imported?  Please share only what was uploaded, which includes what GraphQL directives you used.  The input types are automatically generated for the automatically generated create mutations -- double checking you don't try to create your own input types for generated queries, because that will cause problems.

Comment: I just want to confirm I am understanding the question correctly. You are creating your own GraphQL backend and want a single FQL for the "anti-pattern" code?

Comment: Your first code sample is JS (TS?) that uses FQL. The second code sample is a GraphQL query. You can't use GraphQL as FQL. You have to use the GraphQL endpoint to run GraphQL queries. See: https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/graphql/endpoints

Comment: FQL is a functional language, and is highly composable. We'll be adding more documentation, specifically around query composition, in the new year. If you need help before then, visit the Fauna Forums and describe what you want to do and what you have tried so far: https://forums.fauna.com/